# OxFORD and CamBRIDGE

Tags: etymology, history, toponyms

All of a sudden the scales fell from my eyes: OxFORD and CamBRIDGE. Is there a serious reference for this - not so surprising, but linguistically amusing - fact that these two prominent university cities (by the way both of them doubled across the ocean) share their names by ways to cross a river?

Comment: I guess the fact is mostly due to the fact that people tended to name their settlements after landmarks which are important to them. A fort and a bridge, a port,  are easily recognisable as such, but there are more of them which sometimes have changed a lot during the time, but still originate from such (like -ham from 'home'). And those exist in many languages.

Comment: When the settlement near the bridge on the river Cam finally grew to ten families, the Planning Committee had a meeting to determine a name for the place...

Comment: I took it for granted that Oxford stems from "ford" - and the joke is that the bridge goes *over* the river and the ford goes *under* (resp. through) the river.

Comment: They are not the only places in the UK which have _ford_ and _bridge_ as part of their name. That's not surprising, for the reason that skymninge gives.

Comment: Bosphorus University is less prominent than those two, but [3-way boat races](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/default.aspx?pageid=438&n=eighth-oxford-cambridge-bosphorus-university-boat-race-to-be-held-1998-08-28) have been held among the three universities. (*[Oxford](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Oxford)* is related to *[Bosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosphorus)*: “The name comes from Greek Bosporos (Βόσπορος),[2] which the ancient Greeks analysed as *bous* βοῦς 'ox' + *poros* πόρος 'means of passing a river, ford, ferry', thus meaning 'ox-ford' ...”)

Comment: I took this for granted (@skymninge and @Barrie). But anyway, thanks for the confirmation. What I wonder about is whether the Cambridge people ever tried to derive some superiority because their ancestors went *over* the river while the Oxford people went *through* the river.

Comment: @jwpat: You provide some etymology of "ford" which looks like stemming from "πόρος". Thanks for that!

Comment: @HansStricker Re: Your comment on bridge v. ford, see my answer below as to the reasons for this. While I have no personal experience of either the cities or the universities (except as a visitor to the cities), personally, there are so many bridge/ford places in England that I doubt anyone pays much attention to it. But also note than Cambridge (as a city) has 1000+ years over Oxford anyway.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here.  If your question is along the lines of [your above comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131650/oxford-and-cambridge#comment272198_131650), please put that in the question.  If your question is about loconyms and manmade water crossings, ask that.  Right now, it may seem obvious to you, but I have no idea exactly what you're asking, and evidenced by your unimpressed reaction to answers, neither do the other participants here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is to do with the origin of place names rather than the English language as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rough count using the [List of towns in England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_England) gives:

- ~30 town names with *bridge*; and
- ~120 with *ford*.

**Cambridge**

The earliest clear evidence of occupation in the area of Cambridge is the remains of a 3,500-year-old farmstead. There is also evidence of widespread Roman settlement, including numerous farmsteads and a village. It would also seem that the bridge was originally built by the Romans.

After the Romans had left, Saxons took over the land ... and renamed it *Grantabrycge* – 'Bridge over the river Granta'. Over time the name evolved to become *Cambridge*, while the river *Granta* became known as the river *Cam* to match the name of the city. [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge)

**Oxford**

The City of Oxford is, however, quite young compared with Cambridge, having been settled only in Saxon times (400 - 1066). It was initially known as *Oxenaforda*, meaning "Ford of the Oxen", and began with the foundation of an oxen crossing in the early 900 AD period. [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford)

**General**

It's noteworthy that the older, Roman, place had a bridge, whereas the more recent, Saxon, place only had a ford. The Romans were great builders of towns, bridges, fortresses, etc., but after they had left much of this fell into disrepair, the country became divided into various kingdoms, and much more fragmented. By the time Oxford was settled, fords were more common than bridges. [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford), [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Britain), [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Roman_Britain)

It is also not surprising that many older places were built next to, and took their names from, rivers and their crossings, because rivers were important routes for travel and trade prior to the coming of the railways.

So, no, it's not particularly surprising that two prominent British university cities have reference to river crossings in their names.

Comment: Your answer perfectly meets my question. I always had the impression that Cambridge were a little bit more "noble" than Oxford - and you give an "explanation" which has to do with more or less advanced ways to cross a river.

Answer (score 2):

Both words can be found in etymological dictionaries. Have you looked at what *etymonline* says? Another serious reference is *A Dictionary of British Place-Names* by Anthony David Mills of University of London. He is [quite dedicated](http://www.amazon.co.uk/A.-D.-Mills/e/B001HD1BN4/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) to demystifying the toponyms of the UK. In the mentioned book, he records:

#### ***Cambridge***

> Cambs.
> *Grontabricc* c. 745, *Cantebrigie* 1086 (DB). ‘Bridge on the River Granta’. Celtic river-name (*see* GRANTCHESTER) + OE *brycg*. The change from *Grant-* to *Cam-* is due to Norman influence. **Cambridgeshire** (OE *scīr* ‘district’) is first referred to in the 11th cent. The later river-name **Cam** is a ‘back-formation’ from the place-name.
>
> Glos.
> *Cambrigga* 1200-10. ‘Bridge over the River Cam’. Celtic river-name (see CAM) + OE *brycg*.

#### ***Oxford***

> Oxon.
> *Oxnaforda* 10th cent., *Oxeneford* 1086 (DB). ‘Ford used by oxen’. OE *oxa* (genitive plural *oxna*) + *ford*. **Oxfordshire** (OE *scīr* ‘district’) is first referred to in the 11th cent.

[Cambs. — Cambridgeshire; Glos. — Glaucestershire; Oxon. — Oxfordshire]

Comment: Of course, that doesn't make me a cow. No, it does not.

Comment: Without your comment I would not have noticed. But surely it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The British Isles have the most unsettled and unpredictable weather in the world, the forecasts can completely change within one hour. But extreme cold or heat, and storms, are rare, hurricanes unknown. This is perfectly explained by the situation : rather tiny islands, on the west side of an large ocean, with a latitude in the range of 50° North. You may have a sunny morning and strong showers in the afternoon, or the reverse.

They are therefore notoriously rainy, and there are a number of rivers, wetlands too, many of strategic importance (see the battle of the Boyle, for instance) ; then, of the fords and bridges where you can cross them and have to control.

And the coast is very indented in a number of places, then a number of town's names ending by "wich" (for the Scandinavian "-vik" = bay), or "-on-sea" too. No point is further than some 100 miles from the sea.

Nothing is similar in continental Europe, America, etc., where everything is big.

Comment: I think the whole weather thing is blown out of proportion. There are surely places in the world where the weather is more unsettled and unpredictable. I think it all goes back to the time when the Romans moved to the British Isles from their nice and sunny Apennine Peninsula and got a rude awakening.

Comment: @Talia Ford Please give examples of places where the weather is even more unpredictable. I have been all over the world and don't know one. Besides, Italy is far from being always "nice and sunny" ; try it in winter : you can have inches of snow, even in Sicilia. But the weather is by far more predictable. India, with the monsoons is much more extreme, but you predict them for the next year with very little margin of error.

Comment: Have you been to Vietnam, Bolivia or visited the mountainous areas of New Zealand? Have you been to Ontario in the Great Lakes area? Have you been to upstate NY?  But what I was thinking of was New England: "Lake Winnipesaukee is located at the southern foothills of the White Mountains in New England--an area that has the most unpredictable weather in the world. New England is the only part of the world where three major storm tracks intersect. Air masses from the North Pole and the Gulf of Mexico regularly collide here."